# Повторный вызов функции

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем привет.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как повторно вызывать функцию после ее завершения (причем бесконечно и через определенное время)?

P.S. Пробовал `setTimeout();` - не получается. Заранее спасибо.

**Обновление**

Так вообще не вызывается. Допустим, у меня такой скрипт:

```
function func1() {
...
setInterval(func1, 1000);
}

function func2() {
...
setInterval(func2, 1000);
}

function func3() {
...
setInterval(func3, 1000);
}
```

Может нужно что-то исправить?

Comment: Если внутри себя, то это рекурсия, setTimeout нужно использовать.
А setInterval принимает функцию, которую и запускает на выполнение раз в промежуток.

Comment: Окей. Спасибо всем.

Comment: @rsandrey, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, не получится через setTimeout, он только один раз отсчитывает время. Нужно setInterval использовать.

Answer (score 0):

[[@rsandrey](/users/20567/rsandrey)](/users/20567/rsandrey), для "бесконечно" - или setInterval, или setTimeout внутри функции на себя же. И желательно в callback-е последнего действия.

Answer (score 0):

Очень маленькая ошибка.

Неправильно:

```
setInterval(func1, 1000)
```

внутри функции.

Правильно после функции (после скобки).

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).